# Codeigniter without index.php changing in config and .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have this issue with codeigniter for my subdomain where I would like to take out index.php but is not working for some reason.

I have set .htaccess with below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|user_guide|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and also config.php index_page settings have been changed like below:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

do you know why it's not working?

Comment: DO you have `mod_rewrite` module enabled in your `Apache`? Check if you have `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` uncommented in your `httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how mine is currently setup, hope this helps.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is mine

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```